# Nuclear norm of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, nuclear-norm

Suppose that 
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} A & C^T \\ C & B \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X, A, B \succeq 0$ are (real) positive semidefinite matrices.

Is it true that the Cauchy-Schwarz like inequality:

$$\|C\|_\ast \leq \sqrt{\|A\|_\ast \|B\|_\ast}$$

holds, where $\|\cdot\|_\ast$ denotes the sum of the singular values?

Comment: Can you give an example? I was not able to generate one.

Comment: Please ignore my comment- my earlier examples had $A$ and $B$ PSD but not $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By padding the matrices with zeroes if necessary, we may assume that $A,B$ and $C$ are square matrices of the same sizes. If $C=USV^T$ is a singular value decomposition, by considering $(V\oplus U)^TX(V\oplus U)$, we may further assume that $C$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$. Hence $A,B,C$ are positive semidefinite and their nuclear norms are precisely their traces.

Since $X$ is positive semidefinite, its $2\times2$ principal minors are nonnegative. Hence $c_i^2\le a_{ii}b_{ii}$ for each $i$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\|C\|_\ast^2=\left(\sum_ic_i\right)^2
&\le\left(\sum_i\sqrt{a_{ii}b_{ii}}\right)^2\\
&\le\left[\sum_i(\sqrt{a_{ii}})^2\right]\left[\sum_i(\sqrt{b_{ii}})^2\right]
\ \text{(Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)}\\
&=\left(\sum_ia_{ii}\right)\left(\sum_ib_{ii}\right)=\|A\|_\ast\|B\|_\ast.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks -- reducing to the case $$Y = Y(M, \Sigma, N) = \begin{pmatrix} M & \Sigma \\ \Sigma & N \end{pmatrix}$$ with $M, N, \Sigma$ positive semidefinite matrices of the same dimension is a nice idea. A couple of comments that can be helpful for others: in our case, we will replace (without loss) $A, C$ by $\tilde A, \tilde C$ with zero padding to obtain square matrices of same dimension as $B$.

Comment: (continuation.) Write $\tilde C = U\Sigma V^T$ via SVD, and write $M = U^T \tilde A U, N = V^T B V$, and note then the matrix $Y(M, N, \Sigma)$ satisfies $\tilde X = Q Y Q^T$, with $Q = U \oplus V$ ($\tilde X$ replaces the blocks $A, C$ in the obvious way with $\tilde A, \tilde C$.) The zero-padding ensures $U, V$ are orthogonal so too is $Q$, whence $Y \succeq 0$. Then we now use the result for $Y$: $\|\Sigma\|_\ast^2 \leq \|U^T \tilde A U\|_\ast \|V^T B V\|_\ast = \|\tilde A\|_\ast \|B\|_\ast$, by unitary invariance of the nuclear norm.

Comment: (continuation.) But now we have $\|\Sigma\|_\ast = \|C\|_\ast$, and $\|\tilde A\|_\ast = \|A\|_\ast$, by construction. This gives the result.

Comment: (By the way, I think you want to consider $U \oplus V$ rather than $V \oplus U^T$.)